# Access a nested property with a string

Tags: javascript

```
var person = {
  name: 'Joe',
  contact: {
    phone: '555'
  }
}

var nameOfPerson = person['name']; //Joe

var str = 'contact.phone';
var phoneToPerson = person[str]; //undefined
```

Is this possible to do somehow? I got some logic where I end up with a string and I need to access a nested property with it.

https://jsbin.com/xehokozaco/edit?js,console

Comment: while `nameOfPerson = person.name`, you could: `phoneToPerson = person.contact.phone`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll have to split the string by the period, and then access each node iteratively. This could be done in a simple `reduce`:

```
var value = str.split('.').reduce(function(p,prop) { return p[prop] }, person);
```

The above would work regardless if `str` contains a period or not, i.e. for `name` as well as `contact.phone`.

Answer (score 4):

You can by splitting the string. the `[..]` operator lets you access object properties by name (and array items index). In a case of nested objects, you simply access them one after the other.

Try like this:

```js
var person = {
  name: 'Joe',
  contact: {
    phone: '555'
  }
}

var nameOfPerson = person['name']; //Joe

var str = 'contact.phone';

var phoneToPerson = str.split('.').reduce(function(o, key) {
  return o[key];
}, person);

alert(phoneToPerson);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var select = "contact.phone";
var value = person;
select.split(".").forEach(function(val){
  value = value[val];
});
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Natively, no. However there are way to do it, like splitting the string by `.` and recursively descend from the `person` object. It's also possible by evaluating the full string in `eval` or `new Function`, but I highly discourage for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is quite old but its strange I can't see very popular "Lodash" solution here which allows to get object nested properties **safely**.

Example:

```
var object = { 
     a: [
       { 
         b: { 
           c: 3 
         } 
       }
     ]
 };

_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c'); // → 3
```

For your example:

```
var person = {
  name: 'Joe',
  contact: {
    phone: '555'
  }
}

var personPhoneProp = 'contact.phone';

_.get(person, personPhoneProp); // -> '555'
```

Documentation: https://lodash.com/docs#get