# if i already know an object`s structure,how can i eval the right value to the object?(javascript)

Tags: javascript

If I have an Object like this:

```
let obj = {
  a:{
    b:{
      c:{
        d:{
         e:'nonono'
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

and I know the structure of the Object like that:

now I want to change the innermost layer of the Object, it is the "e" property.
I want to assign another value to "e".
I don't want like these ways below:

1. `obj.a.b.c.d.e = 'another value';`
2. `var str1 = 'a.b.c.d.e';
   obj[str1[0]][str[1]][str[2]][str[3]][str[4]];`
3. `var str1 = 'obj.a.b.c.d.e';
   var str = str1 + "='another value'";
   eval(str);`

above these, I can change the property 'e' of the Object's Value,
but I think it`s not grace to express what I mean.

If I have the Array like that:
`var arr= [a,b,c,d,e]`, I want to recursion a function to find the innermost layer Of the Object, but I try, if I reach the innermost layer of the Object, I lose the quote of the Object..... So I can't change the Object's Value that I want.
I think I run these code, if you can help me to run.

```js
let obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: {
          e: 'nonono'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
let funKeepCite = (obj, index) => {
  if (obj[arr[index]]) {
    funKeepCite(obj[arr[index]], index + 1);
  } else {
    obj = 'test'
  }
}
funKeepCite(obj, 0)
console.log('the result', obj)
```

I can't change the value, I think I lose the quote of the Object, but the Answer of my question is use `for .. in`, and it can keep the quote of the Object, I am confused of these.

Comment: "lose the quote of the Object"?

Comment: if you already know it's structure, then `obj.a.b.c.d.e = 'another value'` is the most obvious way to change the value of `obj.a.b.c.d.e` - your two other ways are simply a) wrong in the case of 2. and absurd in the case of 3.

Comment: Please show us your attempt at writing the recursive function, we cannot help you at fixing it otherwise.

Comment: There are a number of duplicates, e.g. [*Access a nested property with a string*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066787/access-a-nested-property-with-a-string) and [*Convert JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference).

Comment: If you want to do that repeatedly, you can use a reference: `let d = obj.a.b.c.d; d.e = 'yes'`. But not that this does not work directly on primitive types.

Comment: what if your object `obj` has more than one properties? would you like to check them as well? would you want to get the node which has the deepest property?

Comment: sorry , i forget to paste my code,here it is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign to `obj` which is just a local variable, you have to assign to a property. Recurse only until the second-to-last index, then use the last one for the assignment:

```
function funKeepCite(obj,index) {
  if (index < arr.length - 1) {
    funKeepCite(obj[arr[index]], index+1);
  } else if (index < arr.length) {
    obj[arr[index]] = 'test';
  } else
    throw new RangeError("there must be at least one property name in the array");
  }
}
```

Alternatively, use recursion with a return value and always assign:

```
function funKeepCite(obj, index) {
  if (index < arr.length) {
    obj[arr[index]] = funKeepCite(obj[arr[index]], index+1);
    return obj;
  } else {
    return 'test';
  }
}
```

Comment: thanx I know your meanning, i forget I have to set the value to last_second property.like these i change my fun.thx bro,your also work well.`let funKeepCite = (obj,index)=>{   
      if(typeof obj[arr[index]] == 'object'){
       funKeepCite(obj[arr[index]],index+1);
      }else{
        obj[arr[index]] = 'test'
      }
}`

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you want this kind

```js
let obj = {
  a:{
    b:{
      c:{
        d:{
         e:'nonono'
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
function recurse(obj, val){
    for(var k in obj){
        if(typeof obj[k] == 'object') recurse(obj[k], val);
        else if(typeof obj[k] == 'string') obj[k] = val;
    }
}
recurse(obj, 'new');
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: That will change **all** values to "new", not just the specified value.

Comment: yep, this is just suggest method.

Comment: thankx, I run the code,it works.but I have a question why 'obj[k]' can keep the quote of the 'obj',so it can change the value.....

Comment: pass object as argument to function means pass referent of object, when we update its reference the original object will be updated too

Comment: ok, i know your meaning,thanx,can u help me see my example of above my func....I lose my mind why i lose reference of object

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the best way to do it but as for your case, and "***you already know the object's structure***"

function `setInnerObjVal` will change the value of all the innermost object in `obj`.

```js
let obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: {
          e: 'nonono'
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //try uncommenting the below codes
  /*,
  x: {
    y: {
      z: {
        val: 'maybe?'
      }
    }
  }*/
};

function setInnerObjVal(obj1, newVal, callback) {
  for (var i in obj1) {
    if (typeof obj1[i] == 'object') {
      setInnerObjVal(obj1[i], newVal, callback);
    } else {
      obj1[i] = newVal;
      if (typeof callback === 'function')
        callback();
      return;
    }
  }
}

//implement a callback to be called when the function is done.
//just in case your object is way way way deeper and you need to wait for the update to finish
var myCallback = function() {
  console.log(obj);
  //or do something else.
}

setInnerObjVal(obj, 'yesyesyes', myCallback);
//console.log(obj); //this will still log the oldvalue 'nonono' in case obj has a very deep object.
```

**NOTE:**

This function will change ***ALL*** objects under `obj`. (*try uncommenting the values x,y,z,val*)

Comment: ok,your code also can work,but result in the end.not keep the oldvalue, in the end         ` console.log(obj)` , this will change value,it will log 'yesyesyes',that`s result~~

Comment: as I have said, this will miss the timing if you have an object with very deep innermost node, like 1000 levels or something. so, the best way is to have a callback function which will be called by the recursion itself after it is finished. as in my example, of course it will still log 'yesyesyes' since `obj` the recursion is completed in a very short time.