# SortPipe passing parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, pipes-filters, angular2-custom-pipes

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { courses } from '../interface/courses';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sort'
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Array<courses>, args: any[]): Array<courses> {
    const sortField = args[0];
      const sortDirection = args[1];
      let multiplier = 1;

       if (sortDirection === 'desc') {
         multiplier = -1;
        }
        
      value.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
  
       if (a[sortField] < b[sortField]) {
            return -1 *multiplier ;
       } else if (a[sortField]> b[sortField]) {
         return 1 *multiplier;
       } else {
         return 0;
        }       
    });

    return value;
  }  
}
```

this is the sort pipe iam using for my application, I need to pass sortFiled **category** as parameter from the below interface list

```
export interface courses {
  courseId?: number;
  trainingPlatform: string;
  courseName: string;
  platformName: string;
  courseUrl: string;
  learningHours: number;
  courseAssignment: {
    assignmentId: number;
    userId: string;
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
    category: string;
    trainingType: string;
    courseId: number;
    courseStatus: string;
    completedDateTime: Date;
  };
}
```

I tried to pass like this **courseAssignment.category** and also **course.courseAssignment.category** both are not working need some help

```
<div class="container d-flex flex-column">
  <h1 class="pt-2 text-primary">My Courses</h1>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
    <form class="mt-3 pl-1 search_bar">
      <input
        class="form-control mr-sm-2"
        type="text"
        placeholder=" Search"
        aria-label="Search"
      />
    </form>
    <div>
      <button mat-raised-button class="m-2">Add Courses</button>
      <button mat-button mat-raised-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
        SortBy <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down"></i>
      </button>
      <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item  (click)="onSortbyParam()">
        Mandatory
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="onSortbyParam1()">
        Non-mandatory
        </button>
      </mat-menu>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card m-2 " >
 <div *ngFor="let course of courseList|sort:[SortbyParam,SortDirection] index as i">
    <div class="card m-2">
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-row row">
        <div
          class="
            col-4
            d-flex
            flex-row
            justify-content-center
            align-items-center
            col-12 col-sm-4
          "
        >
          <img
            src="https://www.plm.automation.siemens.com/media/global/en/Artificial-Intelligence-AI-Automotive-AT_tcm27-91268.jpg"
            alt="image"
            class="image"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
          <h2 class="card-title">{{ course.courseName }}</h2>
          <h3 class="text-muted">
            Start Date: {{ " " + course.courseAssignment.startDate }}
          </h3>
          <h4>
            <strong>Days left</strong> :{{
              calculateDiff(course.courseAssignment.endDate)
            }}
          </h4>
          <br />
          <mat-checkbox
            (click)="setStatusOfUser(course.courseId)"
            [checked]="course.courseAssignment.courseStatus == 'Completed'"
            [disableRipple]="true"
            >Mark as Completed</mat-checkbox
          >
          <br />
          <p class="card-text">{{ course.trainingPlatform }} Platform</p>
          <br />
        </div>
        <div
          class="
            d-flex
            flex-column
            justify-content-center
            align-items-center
            col-6 col-sm-4
          "
        >
          <p class="text-uppercase" style="color: #ff0000">
            {{ " " + course.courseAssignment.category }}
          </p>
          <h3 class="text-muted mt-3">
            End Date: {{ " " + course.courseAssignment.endDate }}
          </h3>
          <div
            *ngIf="course.courseAssignment.courseStatus === 'Completed'"
            class="text-muted"
          >
            completed Date:
            {{ course.courseAssignment.completedDateTime | date }}
          </div>

          <div
            *ngIf="course.courseAssignment.courseStatus === 'Completed'"
            class="mt-2"
          >
            <a href="https://talent.capgemini.com/">View Certificate</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

whem iam clicking the button iam setting the args like this in TS file but its not working.

```
onSortbyParam() {
    this.SortbyParam = 'courses.courseAssignment.category';
    this.SortDirection = 'asc';
    console.log(this.SortbyParam);
  }

  onSortbyParam1() {
    this.SortbyParam = 'courses.courseAssignment.category';
    this.SortDirection = 'desc';
    console.log(this.SortbyParam);
  }
```

Comment: You are trying to access a nested property within a string path, and I'm not sure if it is possible to do it using vanilla JS. You can use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) or try any other solution in that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)

Comment: Just an observation: if you will only need Lodash for that specific case, consider implement a function that will do it for you instead of load the entire Lodash library, that way you will not load unused functions

Comment: What are you getting in `value` and `args` array in the Pipe? Can you share the usage of the pipe as well?

Comment: @KanishkAnand can you check once i have also added the usage of the pipe

Answer (score 0):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33066839/7374524)

> You'll have to split the string by the period, and then access each node iteratively. This could be done in a simple reduce

So in your code when you are trying to reach the value to sort you can use this:

```
value.sort((a: any, b: any) => {  
    if (getSortProperty(a) < getSortProperty(b)) {
         return -1 *multiplier 
.
.
.

function getSortProperty(item) {
    return sortField.split('.').reduce(function(node,prop) { return node[prop] }, item);
}
```

But also in your HTML code, you need to change the sortField from:

```
this.SortbyParam = 'courses.courseAssignment.category';
```

to:

```
this.SortbyParam = 'courseAssignment.category';
```

Since you are accessing the property from an item of the array, which is already a course element itself.

Comment: i also want to sort on the basis of end date how can i do it.... th

Comment: If you want to make it generic, pass it as an argument to the pipe as well and sort just like you did.

Comment: You are welcome. If it is working, please assign it as the correct answer.